# Flutter Multi Select throws setState() called after dispose():

Tags: flutter, multi-select

I have following 2 drop down in my code
one is drodown and other one is multi select drop down

```
dropdownButtonFormField(
                          value: dropdownValueLvl,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.leaderboard_outlined),
                          ),
                          isExpanded: true,
                          hint: Text('Location'),
                          onChanged: (String value) {
                            // This is called when the user selects an item.
                            // dropdownValueLvl = value;
                            if (mounted) {
                              setState(() {
                                dropdownValueLvl = value;
                                _selectedRoles;
                              });
                            }

                          
                          },
                          validator: (String value) {
                            if (value?.isEmpty ?? true) {
                              return 'Please select Location ';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          items: _locddl.map((item) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: item.id,
                              child: Text(item.locationyName),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),

 FutureBuilder(
                            future:
                                Provider.of<Salesmans>(context, listen: false)
                                    .getUser(),
                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                AsyncSnapshot<Salesman> snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                  ConnectionState.done) {
                                return MultiSelectField<DdlValues>(
                                    //key: _multiSelectKey,
                                    // initialValue: _listRoles
                                    //     .where((element) => _editeSalesman.ddlRoles
                                    //         .contains((element).id))
                                    //     .toList(),
                                    initialValue: _selectedRoles,
                                    buttonText: 'Select Roles',
                                    title: 'Select Roles',
                                    stream: _listRoles,
                                    onConfirm: (values) {
                                      _selectedRoles = values;
                              
                                    });
                              } else {
                                return CircularProgressIndicator();
                              }
                            }),
```

All crud operation are performed properly but If I validate form and select Normal drop down and then select value from multi select drop down, It throws setState() called after dispose():

MultiSelectField.dart as follow

```
class MultiSelectField<V extends DdlValues> extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<V> stream;
  final List<V> initialValue;
  final FormFieldSetter<List<V>> onConfirm;

  final String buttonText;
  final String title;

  const MultiSelectField({
    Key key,
    @required this.stream,
    @required this.initialValue,
    @required this.onConfirm,
    @required this.buttonText,
    @required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MultiSelectFieldState createState() => _MultiSelectFieldState<V>();
}

class _MultiSelectFieldState<V extends DdlValues>
    extends State<MultiSelectField<V>> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return StreamBuilder(
    //     stream: widget.stream,
    //     builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<V>> snapshot) {
    print(widget.initialValue);
    print("Mainwid Key" + widget.key.toString());
    //MultiSelectDialogField
    return MultiSelectDialogField(
      // key: widget.key,
      buttonText: Text(widget.buttonText),
      title: Text(widget.title),
      items: widget.stream
          .map((item) => MultiSelectItem(item, item.name))
          .toList(),
      initialValue: widget.initialValue,
      onConfirm: widget.onConfirm,
      listType: MultiSelectListType.LIST,
      validator: (List value) {
        if (value?.isEmpty ?? true) {
          return 'Please select Roles ';
        }
        return null;
      },
    );

    // });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier in My code, If I validate then following save was called

```
Future<void> _saveForm() async {
   final isValid = _form.currentState.validate();
   FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); // This line was causing issue
   bool isSuccess = true;
   if (!isValid) {
     return;
   }
   // save code

}
```

If Validate form and select Dropdown value and then Multi select value was throwing setState() called after dispose():

I changed code as below and now its working

```
Future<void> _saveForm() async {
    final isValid = _form.currentState.validate();
   
    bool isSuccess = true;
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); // move this line to after if condition
    // save code

}
```